# `stopCluster` in `R snow` freeze

Tags: r, hpc, snow

I was running a Monte Carlo simulation in cluster computers with `snow` and `R`. All went well until `R` hit the line of `stopCluster`, at which `R` freeze and finally exceeded the wall time. I do not see the problem of `stopCluster`.

The following is a simplified version my `R` script.

```
simu <- function(rep_worker, n_used) {
  theta_simu <- c()
  for (i in 1 : rep_worker) {
    theta_simu[i] <- mean(rnorm(n_used))
  }
  theta_simu
}
library(Rmpi)
library(snow)
np <- mpi.universe.size() - 1
cl <- makeCluster(np, type = "MPI")
## go go go
n_used <- 1e4
rep_worker_list <- rep(1, np) # each worker do one `simu`
theta_cluster <- clusterApply(cl, rep_worker_list, simu, n_used)
theta_cluster
stopCluster(cl)
mpi.exit()
```

The above script was saved as `test_stack.R` under the directory `monte-carlo/R`. The `pbs` script I sent to the server is the following.

```
#!/bin/bash

#PBS -N test
#PBS -l walltime=00:30:00
#PBS -l nodes=3:ppn=8
#PBS -l pvmem=8gb

module load R/3.3.1
module load openmpi/gcc/2.0.0
cd monte-carlo/R

# For snow jobs, use 'mpiexec -n 1'
mpiexec -n 1 R CMD BATCH test_stack.R
```

A part of the `Rout` file was listed below. It stop at `stopCluster()`.

```
> simu <- function(rep_worker, n_used) {
+   theta_simu <- c()
+   for (i in 1 : rep_worker) {
+     theta_simu[i] <- mean(rnorm(n_used))
+   }
+   theta_simu
+ }
> library(Rmpi)
> library(snow)
> np <- mpi.universe.size() - 1
> cl <- makeCluster(np, type = "MPI")
    23 slaves are spawned successfully. 0 failed.
> ## go go go
> n_used <- 1e4
> rep_worker_list <- rep(1, np) # each worker do one `simu`
> theta_cluster <- clusterApply(cl, rep_worker_list, simu, n_used)
> theta_cluster
[[1]]
[1] 5.54539e-05

[[2]]
[1] 0.0009270881

... (I deleted the rest to save space)

> stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Do you know you are using the correct compiler (whatever gcc/2.0.0 means)?  I also recommend to check out Rhpc package, it's communication is notably faster on large MPI universes.

Comment: @OttToomet I think the compiler is correct. Our HPC guy told me so. I will take a look of Rhpc. By the way, if the compiler was misspecified, slaves/workers would not be spawned in the first place, right?

Comment: Who knows.  I guess it it is substantially off, then it will immediately complain.  But in case of some minor version differences...I am not sure.

Comment: I also checked my former code--it is basically the same (using ```mpi.quit()``` instead of ```mpi.exit()```) and it worked.  I also had some sort of crashes there, I guess it was related to closing MPI and not stopping cluster.  I did not care too much about those as the job was already done.  And later it just worked.

Comment: That is my current strategy. Run `mpi.exit()` to detach the nodes and leave `Rmpi`, then run `mpi.quit()`, which will report an error (because `Rmpi` package has been dismantled) and exit the servers.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I learned the answer: The version of OpenMPI is the key.

The freezup with stopCluster is solved if you use OpenMPI 1.6.5 and instead of calling stopCluster() from the parallel package, call the one from snow. Know what I mean? replace stopCluster() with

```
snow::stopCluster()
```

And, for good measure, we explicitly call

```
Rmpi::mpi.quit()
```

at the end.

There has been a hang in stopCluster from parallel when using MPI as long as I can remember, but the snow::stopCluster did solve the issue until we rebuilt the R packages with OpenMPI >= 2. If you compile against OpenMPI > 2, then the hang with stopCluster happens, no matter which stopCluster you use.

It appears OpenMPI 1.6.5 is the exactly correct one.

If you use Openmpi > 1.6.5 but < 2, then the hang does not happen, but there is an intriguing warning message about forks:

```
> library(Rmpi)
> library(parallel)
> sessionInfo()
----------------------------------------------------------------------
A process has executed an operation involving a call to the
"fork()" system call to create a child process.  Open MPI is currently
operating in a condition that could result in memory corruption or
other system errors; your job may hang, crash, or produce silent
data corruption.  The use of fork() (or system() or other calls that
create child processes) is strongly discouraged.

The process that invoked fork was:

  Local host:          [[44893,1],0] (PID 35793)

If you are *absolutely sure* that your application will successfully
and correctly survive a call to fork(), you may disable this warning
by setting the mpi_warn_on_fork MCA parameter to 0.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Several years ago, we hit that because somebody was using GOTO BLAS in an R function that triggered some OpenMP matrix threads to pop open and the jobs would sit forever, not failing, not calculating.  This reminds me of that.

Comment: Thanks @pauljohn32, is there any way to overcome the problem with OpenMPI > 2?

Answer (score 0):

Add `mpi.close.Rslaves()` before `stopCluster()`.